# REST API to retrieve block storage metric for Read/Write bytes count

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am trying to find REST APIs exposed by IBM cloud to monitor the read/write byte count for block storage.

I am looking for APIs that **would not** use any monitoring plugins/agents like collectd or nimsoft.

I found that there is an option to select monitoring options like basic, advanced and premium while ordering a device from *control.softlayer.com*. . The 'basic' option does give monitoring information of cpu, **disk** etc, however I am in lookout for the APIs by which such monitoring data could be retrieved so that I could use the API in my code to calculate utilisation.

An example of what kind of APIs I am searching can be found with respect to Google Cloud Platform in the below link :
https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp#gcp-storage

Answer (score 0):

Currently the portal goes through the Api so commonly if it doesn't display the information you require (just like GCP) for SL Storage, then it´s most likely that the sl api will return the same.

I performed api tests and the basic option (or greater) from monitoring plugins is the closest option to retrieve that kind of information, but take in count you`ll retrieve the same data just like the control portal UI displays.

Or on the other hand you could submit a SoftLayer ticket requesting the implementation of this metrics just like GCP.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes correct I understand what you say. I did not see read/write bytes count on the portal and also searched through the API docs, nothing related to read/write was found.